# Trying to get a colored bar in a table

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have a bar with green and red for percentages in a calculation, now im trying to add another color, yellow, to the same bar for another stat and I cant seem to get it right in my css or php.  Here is the current code I have for the green/red combo that works.  What do I need to change to get it right?  Thanks

```
td.graph .all {
    background: green;
    height: 18px;
}

td.graph .right {

    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    background: red;
    height: 18px;
}

echo '</td><td class="graph"><div class="all" style="width:100%"><div class="right" style="width:' . $right . '%"></div>'
```

I'll be adding a new variable that will hold the yellow size and im trying to figure out what I need to get it right.  Thanks

Comment: Could you set up a JS Fiddle (jsfiddle.com)? It will make it a lot easier to understand and help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate div for each color. Then float them left. You can use css percentages to size them.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9UqN/

```
td { border: 1px solid gray;  height: 50px; width: 300px; }
td.graph .bar {
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
}
.green { background: green; width: 60%; }
.red { background: red; width: 10%; }
.yellow { background: yellow; width: 30%; }

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="graph">
            <div class="bar green"></div>
            <div class="bar red"></div>
            <div class="bar yellow"></div>            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you need the green div to fill the entire back area (100%), then I would place red and yellow inside of the green div. Then float them right and use percentages to size them.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9UqN/1/

```
td { border: 1px solid gray;  height: 50px; width: 300px; }
td.graph div {
    height: 18px;
}
.green { background: green; width: 100%; }
.bar { float: right; }
.red { background: red; width: 10%; }
.yellow { background: yellow; width: 30%; }

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="graph">
            <div class="green">
                <div class="bar red"></div>
                <div class="bar yellow"></div>    
            </div>                    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a new class in your CSS to handle the new td that you want to be yellow.

```
td.graph .yellow {
 background: yellow;
 //any other css you want here
}
```

then you can just add a `<div class="yellow">`